# Задача в книге Кормена "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ"

Tags: математика

объясните, пожалуйста, как решить эту задачку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В книге вот такое определение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. я должен доказать, что, например, в первом случае [lgn]! = O(n^k), правильно? Подскажите, с чего начать. Хочу разобраться.

Comment: Я бы начал с формулы Стирлинга...

Comment: Если взять логарифм, то получается, что для полиномиально ограниченной функции `lg(f)=O(lg(n))`. Видимо, вам нужно найти ограничение логарифма первой функции (через соотношение Стирлинга)  и показать, что оно не укладывается в O большое (вероятно, там будет омега)

Comment: Ладно, ответ такой: первая не ограничена, вторая - ограничена.

Comment: @MBo А что значит "Если взять логарифм"? У нас же функция f(n)=[lgn]! Почему мы берем логарифм от f(n)?

Comment: @justify Потому что нужно сравнивать функцию с n^k, а это непросто. Проще прологарифмировать обе стороны, чтобы сравнивать с klogn

Comment: @MBo А где можно почитать про такой способ подробнее(упрощения выражений с помощью логарифмов)? Или это обычная практика, когда мы с двумя выражениями делаем одинаковое действие(например, возводим в степень)? Сорри за возможно глупые вопросы, просто не сильно разбираюсь в этом, только учусь

Comment: С логарифмами - думаю, везде, где сравниваются функции со степенной. Подобно тому, как  же в нахождении пределов делят одно на другое, чтобы получить попроще и яснее выражения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `Ceil(logn)` (а у вас указаны именно такие скобки с округлением вверх) имеет ограничение `Theta(logn)`, поскольку оно не превосходит значения `logn+1`, и `(logn+1)/logn==>C` (стремится к единице, константе). Для строгого доказательства таких моментов, думаю, будет много, но заниматься ими не хочется. Благодаря `Theta` будем использовать просто `f(n)=(log(n))!`

Нужно показать, как сравнивается `f(n) ? O(n^k)`. Со степенной функцией сравнивать трудно, возьмем от обеих сторон логарифмы, и нужно показать сравнение `log(f(n)) ? k*log(n)`

По формуле Стирлинга `log((log(n))!) = Theta(logn*loglogn)`. Сравниваем с логарифмом степенной функции

```
 logn*loglogn  ??  k*logn   //делим на logn
 loglogn  ??    k
```

Но `k` - константа, а слева - бесконечно (хоть и медленно) растущая функция, её рост описывается как `омега_малое(n)`. Таким образом,

```
logn*loglogn = w(n)*logn
```

и   `f(n)=(log(n))! ===  w(n) * Theta(n^k)  > O(n^k)`, т.е. **не является** полиномиально ограниченной